# Can't load html file to webview

Tags: iphone

Here is my code :

NSString *path1 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewSouthWales.html"];

```
NSURL *pageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];
//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pageURL];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I am getting output in my webview as :
like

........

instead of giving me proper look of that file it shows page source code.

Please help ...
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am loading this html file from Resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First prefer pathForRessource ofType

pathNSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NewSouthWales" ofType:@"html"];

And then if the file is local why send a request ?
Just use :

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NewSouthWales" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *baseurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];

    NSData *pathData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path1];
//Check first if the file path's data is captured. if true, load the html on the web view

   if (pathData) {
        [webView loadData:pathData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:baseurl];
  }
```